# Popular ListView com dados do Firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase

Estou tentando inserir os dados do meu banco Firebase em uma `ListView`, mas, sem sucesso.
O banco contém um "nó principal", chamado "ocorrencias" e dentro tenho algumas informações, que eu queria disponibilizar em uma `ListView` (segue imagem do banco).

[image: Banco firebase, com dados que vão para a listview]
Alguém por gentileza, consegue me dar uma ajuda?

Abraços.

Comment: Qual código vc ja implementou e não roda? Se possível especificar mais

Comment: Segue o código como resposta Luccas.

Answer (score 0):

Esse é o código que estou fazendo...
O que está errado?
[image: Meu código]